# List files from directory with php and link them

Tags: php, file

I have a remote directory on my server, and i would like to list all files with a php code under each other. The files are TXT Files for example:

```
1.txt,
2.txt
and so on...
```

I'm now in this stage:

```
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
$thelist .= '<a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a><br>';
}
}
closedir($handle);
}

<ul><?php echo $thelist; ?></ul>
```

but how to exclude the php main file from the list?
Thank you!

Comment: People here __do not__ write code for you. They help you with problems in your code, which you write by yourself.

Comment: Webservers usually have a built-in option to create an index file automatically for a directory.

Comment: Thanks so much for your kind info.

Comment: I'm now in this stage:

if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
$thelist .= '<a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a><br>';
}
}
closedir($handle);
}

<ul><?php echo $thelist; ?></ul>

Comment: `$file != 'main.php'`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to exclude the main file. You could easily check with `$file === basename(__FILE__)`, if you don't use a recursive list of files and folders. You could also use `strpos($file, ".php") == strlen($file)-4` to remove all .php files from your list.

```
<?php
    $path = "./";
    $list = array();
    if($handle = opendir($path)){
        while(($file = readdir($handle)) !== false){
            if(in_array($file, array(".", ".."))){
                continue;
            }

            // Static Removement
            if($file === "index.php"){
                continue;
            }

            // Dynamic Removement
            if($file === basename(__FILE__)){
                continue;
            }

            // Exclude all PHP files
            if(strpos($file, ".php") == strlen($file)-4){
                continue;
            }

            // Add to List
            $list[] = '<li><a href="'.$path.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
?>
<ul>
    <?php echo implode("\n", $list); ?>
</ul>
```

Sincerely,
Sam.